# How to Retrieve current location using GPS co-ordinates in android?

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager, reverse-geocoding

I had retrieved the GPS co-ordinates programatically successfully but i want to track actual location(i.e pune/Banglore/Mumbai)likewise from that co-ordinates so how should it be possible?

Comment: http://www.dizworld.com/2012/09/android-gps-location-finder-demo.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do reverse GeoCoding:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.getDefault());
```

Here is a tutorial
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/location/geocoding.html

Answer (score 0):

Do You mean address, right? Check it out:

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

at the bottom of the page, you got code example :)